# how to convert high quality .wmv file using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-conversion

Please guide me how to solve this issue. Below is what I got when try to convert wmv format file to .flv.

```
ffmpeg -i full.wmv -ar 48000 -ab 192000 -b 293000 -r 15 -s 640x480 full.flv
FFmpeg version SVN-r13582, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=${prefix}/lib --shlibdir=${prefix}/lib --bindir=${prefix}/bin --incdir=${prefix}/include/ffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libfaad --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-liba52 --enable-libtheora --extra-cflags=-Wall -g -fPIC -DPIC --cc=ccache cc --enable-swscale --enable-libdc1394 --enable-nonfree --disable-mmx --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --disable-decoder=libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis
  libavutil version: 49.7.0
  libavcodec version: 51.58.0
  libavformat version: 52.16.0
  libavdevice version: 52.0.0
  libavfilter version: 0.0.0
  built on May  3 2009 12:07:18, gcc: 4.3.2
[wmv3 @ 0x6db7d13f76c0]Reserved RES_SM=2 is forbidden

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, asf, from 'full.wmv':
  Duration: 00:35:31.91, start: 3.000000, bitrate: 1801 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3, yuv420p, 448x352, 1600 kb/s, 25.00 tb(r)
File 'full.flv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, flv, to 'full.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 293 kb/s, 15.00 tb(c)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.1
[wmv3 @ 0x6db7d13f76c0]Reserved RES_SM=2 is forbidden
Error while opening codec for input stream #0.1
```

It would be helpful if anyone could give the correct command instead of what I used

```
ffmpeg -i full.wmv -ar 48000 -ab 192000 -b 293000 -r 15 -s 640x480 full.flv
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see from a [relevant FFmpeg-devel mail](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2009-March/066151.html), it's a WMV mode still unsupported by `FFmpeg`; with a little search, it turns out that, instead, `mplayer` seems to support it (if compiled with the [relevant flag](http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/open-source-software/98654-cant-play-files-encoded-wmv3-archlinux.html#post957452)).

Anyhow, I don't see how is this related with PHP or programming in general, I voted to move it to SuperUser.

Comment: My question is related to php programming, and if any one could get an answer for this I prefer they would explain in relation with php & ffmpeg, thats why I posted here

Comment: Well, it's much more related with ffmpeg than with PHP, since the problem lies all in its WMV decoder stage. :) Anyhow, I already told you where's the problem, if @Bob Fanger says that they fixed it, you should update ffmpeg, otherwise you should try with mplayer as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your ffmpeg to 0.6 (2010) and try again.

Comment: is it sure that if its ffmpeg 6 then the .wmv file will convert to .flv or any other formats